# User Kernel split in 64bit Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, 64bit, virtual-memory, x86

What is the default user/kernel split in the 64bit linux ?

I read [`Documentation/x86_64/mm.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt) (which someone pointed out), but I could not make out. Can somebody provide a direct answer (something like 3GB/1GB for 32bit implementation).

Comment: Do you mean the split for memory?

Comment: @Kevin Yes. I meant the split of the memory.

Answer (score 8):

Like the docs say, user space gets 2<sup>47</sup> bytes = 128TiB, and kernel gets 512MiB. The rest of the address space goes to various parts of the system, along with a few unusable holes.

Comment: 64bit kernel gets less memory than 32bit,  why?