# How much RAM can an application allocate on 64-bit x86 Linux systems?

Tags: kernel, hardware, virtual-memory, pae, ram

Is it true that a single application can not allocate more than 2 GiBs even if the system has GiBs more free memory when using a 32-bit x86 PAE Linux kernel? Is this limit loosened by 64-bit x86 Linux kernels?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A 32-bit process has a 32-bit address space, by definition: “32-bit” means that memory addresses in the process are 32 bits wide, and if you have 2<sup>32</sup> distinct addresses you can address at most 2<sup>32</sup> bytes (4GB). A 32-bit Linux kernel can only execute 32-bit processes. Depending on the kernel compilation options, each process can only allocate 1GB, 2GB or 3GB of memory (the rest is reserved for the kernel when it's processing system calls). This is an amount of virtual memory, unrelated to any breakdown between RAM, swap, and mmapped files.

A 64-bit kernel can run 64-bit processes as well as 32-bit processes. A 64-bit process can address up to 2<sup>64</sup> bytes (16EB) in principle. On the [x86_64 architecture](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt), partly due to the design of x86_64 [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)s, there is currently a limitation to 128TB of address space per process.

Answer (score 6):

32-bit processes can only allocate up to 1, 2, 3, or about 4GB, depending on which memory split was chosen when the 32-bit kernel was built. 32-bit processes on a 64-bit kernel can allocate about 4GB. 64-bit processes on a 64-bit x86-64 kernel can allocate [up to 128TiB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32244/user-kernel-split-in-64bit-linux).